# Story impressions are not available in the FQL Insights table

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-insights

We are trying to get some insights data for our Facebook App using a server side script. The problem is that we do not see any valuable data in the FQL Insights Table for the cases we are interested in: the "Story impressions" and any "Clicks". At the same time the statistics are available in app insights section in facebook admin panel. We have tried all types of the Access Token but with the same result. It seems that not all metrics data is available for FQL. Are we doing something wrong? Is there any way to get these insights data using Insights API?

Thanks.

The App ID: 321206841333892
Here are some sample queries we use:

Sample FQL request1:
Metric   post_impressions

```
Request:https://graph.facebook.com/fql
 params:Array
(
    [q] => {"post_impressions|lifetime":"SELECT metric, value, end_time, period FROM insights WHERE object_id=321206841333892 AND metric='post_impressions' AND period=period('lifetime') AND end_time<=end_time_date('2013-04-09') AND end_time>=end_time_date('2013-03-10')"}
    [access_token] =>ACCESS_TOKEN
    [method] => GET
)
```

Result: empty set.

Sample FQL request2:
Metric   application_active_users

```
Request:https://graph.facebook.com/fql
 params:Array
(
    [q] => {"application_active_users|day":"SELECT metric, value, end_time, period FROM insights WHERE object_id=321206841333892 AND metric='application_active_users' AND period=period('day') AND end_time<=end_time_date('2013-04-09') AND end_time>=end_time_date('2013-03-10')","application_active_users|week":"SELECT metric, value, end_time, period FROM insights WHERE object_id=321206841333892 AND metric='application_active_users' AND period=period('week') AND end_time<=end_time_date('2013-04-09') AND end_time>=end_time_date('2013-03-10')","application_active_users|month":"SELECT metric, value, end_time, period FROM insights WHERE object_id=321206841333892 AND metric='application_active_users' AND period=period('month') AND end_time<=end_time_date('2013-04-09') AND end_time>=end_time_date('2013-03-10')"}
    [access_token] =>ACCESS_TOKEN
    [method] => GET
)
```

Result: 25 significant values.

Comment: We have queried all the metrics documented on the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/ but most of them give no results.

Comment: Try getting this with an [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/).

Comment: We've tried app access token as well as user access token with different permission options. The result is always the same, we get some data but nothing for the metrics that represent "Story Impressions" in the app admin->Insights->Traffic.